# Mathematical Proofs

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, solution-verification

Is this the proper site to ask about the correctness of one's proof? The proofs I would intend on asking questions about are elementary mathematics proofs such as a proof about infinitely many primes, induction equalities and inequalities, etc... Or is there another site for "Proof Review" Similar to the stackexchange site "Code Review"??

Comment: See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/is-it-ok-to-ask-whether-my-proof-solution-is-correct-if-i-dont-have-any-particu) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper). Short answer: yes.

Comment: But you might first look around for others questions about those problems. I'm sure there have many proofs of, for example, the infinity of primes on this website, you might find yours has already been discussed.

Comment: This question is related, too: [Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions)